# Eclipse: multiple Project Settings windows

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

Is there any way to show multiple "Project Properties" windows in parallel in Eclipse (maybe using a plugin)?

I have 2 separate projects and I want to copy some configuration settings from one to the other.

Note: the 2 projects are under the same workspace (I could get around this by moving one project to another workspace and open 2 Eclipse instances, but I'd prefer not to resort to that).

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible. But as a workaround, you can compare in the _Navigator_ view the `.settings` folders where these project-specific settings are stored.

Comment: @howlger Thanks for the tip: I've opened the Navigator view, I see the .settings folders for both projects, but how do I actually do the comparison between the files?

Comment: Select both folders, right-click and choose _Compare With > Each Other_.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help much :) The 2 projects are quite different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up moving one project to another workspace and opening 2 Eclipse instances.